# Autocomplete jquery removing the menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was designing a menu similar to this one below, but I can't get the dropdown menu to disappear once the cursor is out of it (the user may scroll down of the page and the menu stays there). Any ideas as to how to do it?

I thought about doing `scrollTop()` in jQuery but it didn't work...

Thank you very much!

http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/30/

Comment: As long as the input is focused the list will remain displayed.. thats the expected behavior... what do you need exaclty

Comment: I need that when the user scrolls down the menu disappears. But because it has position absolute It does not. Thank you!